# How to format file excel before export?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, export-to-excel

I want to controll layout this file before exported it.Example: I want fix width column, the title color, the border table or hightline one row or wordwrap by code before export.I using **Angularjs** in my project.Can give me some suggestions library support this? Like this:
 [Picture file excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdQAn.png)

When i try using alasql library to set width column,i recieve this bug.
[Picture Bugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5zph.png)

How can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.factory('Excel', function ($window) {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
    base64 = function (s) { return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); },
    format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) };
return {
    tableToExcel: function (tableId, worksheetName) {
        var table = $(tableId),
            ctx = { worksheet: worksheetName, table: table.html() },
            href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        return href;
    }
};
})
```

calling function

```
  $scope.exportToExcel = function (tableId) { // ex: '#my-table'          
    var exportHref = Excel.tableToExcel(tableId, 'sheetname');
    $timeout(function () { location.href = exportHref; }, 100); // trigger download
}
```